# Janus Graph - gremlin-server - Java Client - Cannot find class file for apache.commons.configuration

Tags: java, client, gremlin, janusgraph

I am trying to access the janus graph on Cassandra through Java Client, but not able to use the properties file through the Client class.

```
public static void main(){

    Cluster cluster = Cluster.open("remote.yaml");
//  Cluster cluster2 = Cluster.build();

    Client client = cluster.connect();
    graph = JanusGraphFactory.open("conf/janusgraph-cassandra-solr.properties");
```

error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type The project was not built
>   since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for
>   org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration. Fix the build path
>   then try building this project    janusgraph      Unknown Java Problem

Comment: Are you using Apache Maven to build your project? What dependencies did you include in your pom.xml?

Answer (score 1):

This questions was also asked on the [`janusgraph-users`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/janusgraph-users/jVjB9P_U6yA) Google Group. My answer from that thread:

> `org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration` is not found in Apache commons-lang. It is in Apache commons-configuration.
>
> There are a lot of dependencies for the JanusGraph/TinkerPop stack, so you're best approach would be to use a tool like Apache Maven or Gradle to manage the dependencies for your project, rather than adding the jars one by one. Please refer to the code examples included with the distribution.